# Apply Durbin Watson test on Prais Winsten Model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am having trouble running a Durbin Watson test on the prais winsten model I generated.

```
value3<-prais.winsten(value1$model)
dwtest(value3)
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute
```

Comment: An error comes up when I do this

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example code, also the error message might be useful.

Comment: @drmariod "Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute"

Comment: try `?formula` for some help on formulas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any reasonable reproducible example is hard to pinpoint where is the issue, this is a kind of default way to go:

```
# Calculate Durbin-Watson                                                                         
ols <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)  

dwtest(y ~ x1 + x2)

prais.winsten.lm(ols)

# Calcuate Autocorrelation and Partial Autocorrelation Coefficients                 
acf(resid(ols),lag.max = 5,plot = FALSE)
pacf(resid(ols),lag.max = 5,plot = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call dtest with the lm function on the list that prais.winsten returns

> From your example it would be:

`dwtest(lm(value3[[1]]))`

When you display value3 you should see somthing like this at the top

> [[1]]
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = fo)

This is what I am referring to.